# How to protect a pressure gauge from condensation in a vacuum steam boiler?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, vacuum, steam, instrumentation, siphon

Pressure gauges are protected from steam condensation in a regular boiler by using a siphon where steam condenses and prevents steam from going further up to the gauge.

However in a vacuum steam boiler when the boiler is re pressurized after use the pressure would push the water in the siphon up to the vacuum gauge.

I currently dont use any siphon and my vacuum gauges are far off (from condensation I guess) after a few boils, how can I prevent that ?

Comment: Something like this? http://ultraeverdryonline.com.au/

Comment: condensation has a mysterious way of messing up the bourdon tubes of pressure gauge. These tubes are made of metal already, so it's not a matter of surface tension/wetting I believe

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a gauge guard?  It's a simple diaphragm that allows pressure to transmit, without the liquid crossing the barrier.

[image]